# Day and night temperature on an earthlike planet with longer rotational period

Tags: the-moon, earth, temperature, tidal-forces

I'm trying to understand the climatic effects of the far future scenario of an Earth-like planet with a reduced rotational speed caused by tidal locking with the moon (day-night period of 28 days, one hemisphere always facing the moon, the other never facing the moon).

I understand that observations of the moon's surface temperature have shown day temperatures of 120°C and freezing cold nights of -230°C.

**How would the day and night temperatures of tidal locked Earth vary?**

I am also interested in climatic effects caused by the reduced tides, coriolis force, increased evaporation, but this may reasonably be outside the scope of this question and it's answers.

Comment: One thing I found out about climate effects is that the Coriolis Effect responsible for e.g. the Trade winds will weaken significantly, changing pattens of the global circulation systems http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_circulation

Comment: just beware that the moon is not a good example: the extreme temperatures are not due to the tidal locking but to the absence of atmosphere. If there were atmosphere the temperature would be "milder" but I reckon that there would be amazing storms